# how to set user name/password in httpget

Tags: java, httpclient

I use Apache HttpComponents to access a web service, and don' know how to set user/password in the request, here is my code:

```
URI url = new URI(query);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test");
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), defaultcreds);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

..

but still it got the 401 unauthorized error.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Pragma: No-cache, Cache-Control: no-cache, Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MemoryRealm", Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 954, Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2012 02:28:49 GMT]
```

I m not sure if its the right way to set user/password? anyone can help? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are on the right track. Perhaps you should check your user credential as the http [error response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) could probably means incorrect username/password or the user does not have the privilege to access the resources. I have the below code which I do basic http authentication and it is working fine.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class Authentication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        DefaultHttpClient dhttpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String username = "abc";
        String password = "def";
        String host = "abc.example.com";
        String uri = "http://abc.example.com/protected";

        try
        {
            dhttpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
            HttpGet dhttpget = new HttpGet(uri);

            System.out.println("executing request " + dhttpget.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse dresponse = dhttpclient.execute(dhttpget);

            System.out.println(dresponse.getStatusLine()    );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            dhttpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

    }

}
```